# One class SVM for concept drift

Tags: python, scikit-learn, svm

I am working on one class classification using python. I am currently using One class SVM as implemented in `scikit-learn`. My data will gradually change in due course of time and the older data will no longer be valid to be used for classification, which is known as concept drift as far as I am aware of. Hence I will have to retrain my classifier as soon as a new sample(or a predetermined number of samples) is added.

However, I have read that One class SVM does not work properly in case of concept drift. Why is it so?

Which other one class classification algorithm can I use if not OSVM in case of concept drift in my dataset?